# How to remove only one remote origin when there are several?

Tags: git

Looking at the git documentation I see that I can delete a remote origin using a command like this:

```
git remote remove origin
```

But what if I have multiple origins and I only want to delete one of them?  In my case it looks something like this:

```
git remote -v 
origin ssh://host1/path/to/project.git (fetch)
origin ssh://host1/path/to/project.git  (push)
origin ssh://host2/path/to/project.git  (push)
```

I only want to delete the last origin.  How do I do this?

Comment: Remove then add?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### TL;DR

```
git config --delete remote.origin.push ssh://host2/path/to/project.git
```

See below for why that's slightly sloppy.

#### Long

There's only one remote named `origin` here.

What it has is three *URLs*.

A remote usually has two URLs: one `fetch` and one `push`.  This is true even if you didn't set a particular `push` URL, as `git remote` will *use* the fetch URL *as* the `push` URL.  In this case, though, someone has configured *two* push URLs.

(If you configure one push URL, the one that you used to see—copied from the `fetch` automatically—goes away, leaving you with just the one push URL you just configured.  So someone must have configured two.)

To delete one particular setting, use:

- `git config`, or
- your editor (possibly *via* `git config`; see below)

To use `git config` to delete a *specific* setting:

```
git config --delete remote.origin.push 'ssh://host2/path/to/project\.git'
```

The backslash (and quotes) here is to make sure that this matches only that specific setting.  The last argument is a *regular expression*, and in regular expressions, the letter `.` matches any character.  So without the backslash this would delete, for instance, `ssh://host2/path/to/projectAgit` if it's in there.

Since host names usually have dots, you might want to backslash those.  However, all of this is just being extra-careful: using `.` to match `.` is usually fine because you probably *don't* have `ssh://host2/path/to/projectAgit`, `ssh://host2/path/to/projectBgit`, and `ssh://host2/path/to/project.git` in there.  (In fact, we *know* you don't as you showed us some output that says so.)  So:

```
git config --delete remote.origin.push ssh://host2/path/to/project.git
```

will actually suffice.

You can also run `git config --edit`, which invokes your chosen editor—the one you use for commit messages and for `git rebase -i`—on your `.git/config` file.  I typically do this to fix typos, for instance.